# Is DMA Appropriate for a Keyboard?

Tags: memory, keyboard, operating-system, cpu, dma

Quick question: is direct memory access something that is appropriate for a keyboard? I know that DMA describes a device interfacing with the motherboard's memory without a CPU, and DMA controller's are notified by something like a keyboard when they need to move data to memory, but is a keyboard as a device itself appropriate for DMA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input from keyboards, insofar as the actual typing, is typically an extremely low speed, maybe 20 characters per second if you are mashing the keys quickly.  DMA is far, far overkill for this task.  An interrupt-driven serial protocol is appropriate.

> DMA controller's are notified by something like a keyboard when they need to move data to memory

Not sure where you got this. DMA controllers are a property of a device and notification to start a transfer would be something initiated by the device driver or device itself.

Comment: I see I was reading wrong, interrupt-driven serial protocol is a strategy for writing to memory?

Comment: No.  It's a communication technique for getting data from a device *without* letting the device DMA to memory.  Process: CPU receives keyboard interrupt, CPU calls device driver for keyboard interrupt, CPU code in driver fetches waiting data from device and puts it in a temporary buffer local, private, and fixed to the device driver until a process asks for keyboard data.  Buffer full?  Throw read data away.